# Why does installing Google SignIn SDK installs Firebase - Cocoa pods

Tags: ios, cocoapods, google-signin

I want to implement Google SignIn in my IOS app. I was adding the sdk using the cocoapods

```
pod 'Google/SignIn'
```

but `pod install` - installs the firebase

```
Using FirebaseAnalytics (3.6.0)
Using FirebaseCore (3.4.5)
Using FirebaseInstanceID (1.0.8)
Using GTMOAuth2 (1.1.4)
Using GTMSessionFetcher (1.1.7)
Using Google (3.0.3)
Using GoogleAppUtilities (1.1.2)
Using GoogleInterchangeUtilities (1.2.2)
Using GoogleSignIn (4.0.1)
Using GoogleSymbolUtilities (1.1.2)
Using GoogleToolboxForMac (2.1.0)
```

How do i remove the Firebase.  I don't need any analytics stuff.  Just the Google SignIn.

Thanks

Comment: They just come in a package, the same applies for android I think. They are packaged together because Google sign in and Firebase are used together by many developers. Try removing them from the root and updating the dependencies.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't want to install other packages of Google then use

```
pod 'GoogleSignIn'
```

It will just install the required packages of `GoogleSignIn`

```
Installing GTMOAuth2 (1.1.4)
Installing GTMSessionFetcher (1.1.7)
Installing GoogleAppUtilities (1.1.2)
Installing GoogleSignIn (4.0.1)
Installing GoogleSymbolUtilities (1.1.2)
Installing GoogleToolboxForMac (2.1.0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. My name is also Rajat.

Comment: Glad it helped you Rajat ;)

Comment: Thanks it worked.  And also i have to follow the Non CocoaPods integration instructions even though i am using CocoaPods https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sdk/